# SPA API MS Azure SSO

Tags: angular, laravel, azure, azure-active-directory

I have an angular frontend and a laravel api backend on different domains using username/password login with jwt token. I have integrated Microsoft Azure AD login with oauth using the following:

1. I have registered the app in Azure, specified my angular callback url and generated client secret. Client secret is in laravel env.
2. Angular redirects to MS login page and on successful login, redirects back to angular with auth code.
3. Angular passes auth code and redirect url to laravel which uses socialite to get access token from MS
4. If user exists (based on email address), user is logged in and jwt token is generated and returned.

This is all working but I am concerned about security. If people can see code and redirect being passed to my api endpoint can they do anything with this code?

I have locked down my MS login to my tenancy.

I have also looked into doing the full authentication on the angular side and then passing the MS token to my api but thought this would be less secure.

Comment: If you are using `https` encryption ,then your app will be more secured.

Comment: `I have locked down my MS login to my tenancy` , As you have already restricted the access only to limited users, chances of unauthorized access will be less.As only the users from your organization will only be able to access the App.

Answer (score 0):

I created **Azure AD SPA Application** like below:

[image]

I used below **authorize** endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
&code_challenge=CodeChallenge
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

[image]

[image]

By using the above generated code, I generated **access token**:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
code_verifier:S256
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
```

[image]

> This is all working but I am concerned about security. If people can see code and redirect being passed to my api endpoint can they do anything with this code?

The auth code is valid only for few minutes and can only be used once when the Angular frontend redirects to the Microsoft login page. This implies that even if the code is intercepted, it would not be possible for someone to access your application using that information.

**If I try to re-use the code**, then the error occurs:

[image]

- And as your application is locked down to the tenancy level, only the users in the organization will be able to access the application which reduces unauthorized access.
- Make sure the MS token is securely provided to your API and validated to make sure it hasn't been tampered with.

**Reference:**

[Azure security baseline for Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/benchmark/azure/baselines/aad-security-baseline?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Farchitecture%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Farchitecture%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json)

[Secure your Azure AD identity infrastructure - Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/steps-secure-identity)

Comment: if the code was intercepted (which would mean the SSL encryption would have been broken and the PKCE challenge would have already happened) and not immediately redeemed by the application for a token, an attacker could conceivably redeem that code themselves from Azure AD if they had the application ID.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the attack vector: If the SPA code was intercepted (which would mean the SSL encryption would have been broken and the PKCE challenge would have already happened) and not immediately redeemed by the application for a token, there is a window of time for an attacker to redeem that code themselves from Azure AD if they have the application ID.

However, if your SSL encryption has been broken it seems like it is game over anyway.